# Pandas df: How do I groupby, aggre to obtain the sum if there is at least 1 valid numerical value?

Tags: pandas

For a groupby, I need to use an agg to obtain the sum and other statistics. But for sum, I want to return nan if all elements in the group is np.nan. I tried writing a lambda function, but it doesn't work. Please assit. Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
        
"name": ['dick','john', 'john', 'john'],
"age": [np.nan, 20, 20,  np.nan]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
var_dict['age']=lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False) if all(ele!=np.nan for ele in x)

df_gpby = df.groupby(['name'], dropna=False).agg(var_dict).reset_index()
```

**Desired Output**
Basically, for Dick = np.nan
while for John = 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you want

```
df = df.groupby('name')['age'].apply(
    lambda x: np.nan if x.isna().all() else x.sum()
    )
```

which returns this

```
name
dick     NaN
john    40.0
```

essentially u need to do the following

1. group by the name
2. for each group find the sum of the ages EXCEPT if all ages are nan set it to nan

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `min_count` parameter. Ensure there is atleast 1 number to be summed.

```
df.groupby('name', as_index = False).sum(min_count = 1)

   name   age
0  dick   NaN
1  john  40.0
```

Comment: Much better approach than the currently accepted answer!